# How to use Vlookup in csv with python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

Original file

[image]

Data source

[image]

Output

[image]

My code is as follows.

```
import pandas as pd

file_dest = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Book1.csv"

# read csv data
book=pd.read_csv(file_dest)
file_source = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Book2.csv"

materials=pd.read_csv(file_source)

Right_join = pd.merge(book,
                      materials,
                      on ='Name',
                      how ='left')

Right_join.to_csv(file_dest, index=False)
```

However, the output is as follows, which looks like it just copied the contents but didn't use Vlookup to insert the data. I had tried it with different kinds of data. The results are all the same (which looks like it just copied the contents). Please help me find out the bugs.

[image]

Comment: You've merged your dataframes on column "Desc", but I don't see this column in your images. What is this column?

Comment: Sorry. It should be "Name". I corrected the code and the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since column names are different in each data source, you have to specify columns to join on in the left and right dataframes. Try this:

```
# assuming materials is your data source with Price column
joined = book.merge(materials,
                  left_on="Custmor",
                  right_on="Name",
                  how ='left')
```